# How to display a unit in an input field with Angular Material?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to display a measurement unit inside an Angular Material input field. It should look like this:
[image]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<span matSuffix>m²</span>` like in the example below:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Room Size</mat-label>
  <input type="text" matInput />
  <span matSuffix>m²</span>
</mat-form-field>
```

See [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#prefix--suffix).